# Pairing functions for rationals

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Can you construct pairing functions for rational numbers? i.e. I want to create some bijective mapping where:$$f: \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$$
I know they exist for the natural numbers/integers... If they don't exist for the rationals, could you please also tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ be bijective.

Let $h:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Z$ be bijective.

Then the composition: $$\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\ni\left\langle p,q\right\rangle \overset{h\times h}{\mapsto}\left\langle h\left(p\right),h\left(q\right)\right\rangle \overset{g}{\mapsto}g\left(h\left(p\right),h\left(q\right)\right)\overset{h^{-1}}{\mapsto}h^{-1}\left(g\left(h\left(p\right),h\left(q\right)\right)\right)\in\mathbb{Q}$$
is bijective.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is one! It's just a hassle to write down explicitly.

However, if you know a pairing function $f:\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ for the naturals, and you know a pairing function $g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$ between the naturals and the rationals, then you can combine them to make
$$
\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q\stackrel{g^{-1}\times g^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb N \times \Bbb N\stackrel{f}{\to}\Bbb N\stackrel g\to \Bbb Q
$$

Comment: Ahhh of course, that would make sense. Thanks :)